# Is it preferable to use Activity.onAttachFragment or Fragment.onAttach to communicate between an Activity and a nested fragment?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-fragments

The Android documentation suggests that to communicate from an activity to a hosted fragment, the fragment can define a callback interface and require that the host activity implement it. The basic pattern involves implementing `onAttach` in your fragment, and casting the activity to a callback inteface. See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity.

Here's an example of providing a fragment some initialization data, as well as listening for a navigation callback.

```
public class HostActivity extends Activity implements FragmentHost {
  @Override
  UiModel getUiModel() {
    return mUiModel;
  }
  @Override
  FragmentNavListener getNavListener() {
    return mNavListener;
  }
...
}

public class HostedFragment extends Fragment {
  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (activity instanceof FragmentHost) {
      FragmentHost host = (FragmentHost) activity;
      setUiModel(host.getUiModel());
      setNavListener(host.getFragmentNavListener());
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Compare this to using `onAttachFragment` in the host activity to explicitly initialize the fragment:

```
public class HostActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
    if (fragment instanceof HostedFragment) {
      HostedFragment hostedFragment = ((HostFragment) fragment);
      hostedFragment.setUiModel(mUiModel);
      hostedFragment.setNavListener(mNavListener);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

To me, it seems like the first pattern has some drawbacks:

1. It makes the fragment harder to use from different activities, since
   since all of those activities must implement the required interface. I can imagine cases where a given fragment instance doesn't require being fully configured by the host activity, yet all potential host activities would need to implement the host interface.
2. It makes the code slightly harder to follow for someone unfamiliar with the pattern being used. Initializing the fragment in onFragmentAttached seems easier to  follow, since the initialization code lives in the same class that creates the fragment.
3. Unit testing using a library like Robolectric becomes harder, since when calling onAttach, you must now implement FragmentHost rather than just calling onAttach(new Activity().

For those of you who've done activity to fragment communication, what pattern do you find preferable, and why? Are there drawbacks to using `onAttachFragment` from the host activity?

Answer (score 6):

I cant speak personally with respect to testing but there is alternatives to fragment / activity callback interface communication.

For example you can use a event bus to decouple the fragments and your activity. An excellent event bus can be found here:

[Otto - An event Bus by Square](https://github.com/square/otto)

It is actively being developed by some very talented engineers at Square. 
You can also use the LocalBroadcastManager that is packaged in the Android Support Library.

[LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

Eric Burke from square has a presentation where he mentions both which can be found here:

[Android App Anatomy](http://www.slideshare.net/burkeeric/android-app-anatomy)

Comment: Otto is now deprecated

Comment: LocalBroadcastManager is deprecated https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager and would recommend this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Answer (score 4):

**Update** : As per the latest guidelines we are supposed to use a **sharedViewModel** class to communicate between fragments and activities.

However if you don't use viewModels and use callbacks, you should still **consider removing onAttachFragment callback as it is deprecated** now.

Instead on onAttachFragment, the suggested way is to add a listener to your fragmentManager who is associated with that transaction using **addFragmentOnAttachListener**.

See the example below:

```
   childFragmentManager.addFragmentOnAttachListener { _, fragment ->
        if (fragment is RetryDialogFragment) {
           //Do your work here.
        }
    }
```

You should also be mindful of where you add this listener. You most probably want to add this listener before you execute the fragment transaction and should make sure that you are not adding the listener more than once.

Comment: Where should be used this listener in case of navigation component? I have BottomNavigationView set up with navigation component and implement this listener in onCreate() of BaseActivity. First time that fragments onAttach() called, this listener notifies, but next time that I called onAttach() manually, listener doesn't notify. Can you help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by calling onAttach() manually?. I am not so familiar with navigation component, but inorder to get notified you have to make the fragment transaction using the same "fragmentManager" on which you have added the "addFragmentOnAttachListener ".

Comment: I have a scenario where the fragment needs to be reloaded after click on a button inside fragment. This happen correct and cause onAttach() method called again, but listener doesn't receive callback again.

Comment: Try asking this as a separate question on stackoverflow with the code containing how you add and reload the fragment.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the `Fragment.onAttach(...)` pattern in my last project. I see two advantages:

1. you can check early that the hosting activity implements the required interface and throw an exception if not
2. there's less risk of holding onto a reference of the hosting context after the fragment has been detached

In order to take advantage of 2., you must not store references to `UiModel` and `NavListener`, as you do in your code sample. Instead, whenever you want to interact with these instances, you should use code like `((FragmentHost) getActivity).getNavListener().onNav(this)`, or alternatively `((FragmentHost) getActivity).onNav(this)`. You could store the fragment host in a field which you set to null in `onDetach(...)` as a middle ground approach, if you want to avoid the constant casting.

I agree that initializing a fragment from the activity that creates it seems more intuitive.

Having said all that, I'm going to skip fragments altogether in my current project. The following post reflects the lessons learned from my last one pretty well: https://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html